# Graph Classification based on degree distribution

Tags: graph-theory

Networks can be classified into different classes based on their degree distribution.

So far I know there are two kind of network

1) [Scale Free Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network) (can be generated using [barabasia and albert's model](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph.html#networkx.generators.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph))

2) Random Networks

[image: Degree Distribution of scale free/random networks]

Are their other kind of networks? How can we generate them?

Answer (score 0):

Another classical network model is Small World networks by Watts and Strogatz. You can have a look at their seminal paper [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v393/n6684/full/393440a0.html)